# Which cars have noise cancelling installed to reduce rolling and engine noise?

Tags: noise

I know that some cars that use [active noise cancelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_noise_control) to reduce the engine and rolling noise in the passenger cabin. Some cars even *reintroduce* engine noise to give the driver some feedback...

My question is: how or where can I find which cars use such systems? This is a technical feature not listed in brochures and too "technical" for the average showroom guy, IMHO.

**Update**

Following a link given in the comments I found another link with a listing of cars and noise levels. [Auto Decibel](http://www.auto-decibel-db.com/)

Comment: Your best bet might be to contact the companies that make the noise cancelling systems (Bose, Harman, others) and ask them what cars use their system.

Comment: I know for sure that car companies develop their own systems, see for example Google Patents and look for "noise canceling car" and you'll see Audi and other German companies, and many smaller companies.

Comment: Just to clarify between your title and the question text...  You do want some type of resource that lists the cars rather than having people just give you the models of cars that happen to have a system, right?

Comment: Yes, it's how or where, not the list specifically that would change all the time. I was thinking more about links where someone mantains those lists or to official entities doing tests on cars.

Comment: Here is a list of the 30 quietest cars in a test by Auto Bild.     http://elevatingsound.com/the-top-30-quietest-cars-a-cabin-noise-test-by-auto-bild/

Comment: Put that list as your answer and it reward it to yourself

Comment: I didn't do that because it was on the page you provided and I felt it would not be fair. If you put it in an answer I would assign it to you and remove from top post

Answer (score 1):

I believe the old Mazda Xedos 9 (and possibly Xedos 6) featured this system

Answer (score 1):

All Lincoln's use Active Noise Control. The entire vehicle is coated with foam to reduce outside noise. Plus the premium speakers creates a noise cancelling signal to ensure that the passenger cabin is quiet.